# Selecting User Defined Types

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types

After I create a type and table using a type, I can't properly see data when I select it. For example, if I do this:

```
create type name_type as object(
type varchar2(50))
final;

create table person(name name_type);

insert into person values (name_type('John'));

select * from person
```

as a result I would get:

```
myUsername.name_type('John')
```

How can I get just "John" when I select data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to reference the field of the record:

```
SQL> select p.name.type from person p;

NAME.TYPE
--------------------------------------------------
John
```